# Selenium alert handling testing approach/ Design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

I am new to Selenium and I am trying typical login page automation and came across below scenario and I want to know the professional approach to handle the situation.

Scenario
Test application login page using valid & Invalid Credentials. When I enter invalid credentials, a pop up comes and inform the user that you have entered wrong user name or password.

My Approach

1. I have created a page-object class to hold all Web elements using Page Factory and exposed Web elements to outside class using some public methods.
2. In the test class I have created objects of the page under test and passed login credentials using testng xml.

Then I ran Testng suit and it ran fine. but the problem is when I pass invalid credentials a popup window is coming and since I have not coded for popuup window I am getting exception.

I know what to do for popup but my real question is should I write a different test class to handle invalid credentials. or my Question how can i write a common code for two different output ie when I enter valid credentials it goes to HomePage and when I enter Invalid i get popuup and I will be in Login which is actually excepted and my test-case should pass.

**Login.java**

```
public void loginToGuru99(String userName,String password){
    this.setUsername(userName);
    this.setPassword(password);
    this.clickOnLogin();
}
```

**TestGuru99LoginPage.java**

```
  @BeforeTest
  public void setup() {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
  }

// @Test(dataProvider="Authentication")


  @Test
  @Parameters({ "sUsername", "sPassword" })
  public void TestGuru99LoginPage(String sUsername,String sPassword) {
      login= new Guru99LoginPage(driver);
      homePage= new Guru99HomePage(driver);
      try{
          login.loginToGuru99(sUsername, sPassword);          
          Assert.assertTrue(homePage.getHomePageDashboardUserName().toLowerCase().contains("manger id : mngr13564"));
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

**Utils.java**

```
public static boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        } finally {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
      }
```

Please let me know the best approach to start with.

Thanks,
Deepu Nair

Comment: In your Test, you are checking a valid login method, so your Test will pass only if you are using the valid credentials and it will fail if you use bad credentials. Isn't it what you expecting?

Comment: I agree with @peetya. You are trying to test two things : valid credentials login succeeds and invalid credentials login fails so you need to have two different test methods, if not different test classes. What would be the value of a test which succeeds whether you pass valid credentials (successful login or invalid credentials (handling the popup).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  @peetya according to me both the testcases should pass and as in both the cases I am getting my expected result.

Comment: @user2611581 : so best approach you are suggesting is to have one more method for handling invalid credentials right ?  I was thinking to avoid duplicate code as well . Thanks alot.since I am new to selenium I was thinking about whether we have any alternative way to achieve this .

Comment: @DeepuNair: if TestGuru99LoginPage.java is your test then I would also suggest considering moving instantiating of the login and home page to the @BeforeTest method and call only the `code` login.loginToGuru99(sUsername, sPassword) `code` along with the Assert.assertTrue or Assert.assertFalse method ..similar to what peetya has in the answer below.

Comment: Thank you @user2611581  . Let me try this today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you expecting different results for both of the test case you have to use different Asserts, but you can use the same methods from your PageObject. As you see the first will pass if you get logged in, and the second will pass only if you don't get logged in.

```
@Test
public void validLogin() {
  // ...
  String username = "validUsername";
  String password = "validPassword";
  login.clickOnLoginButton(username, password);
  Assert.assertTrue(homePage.getHomePageDashboardUserName().toLowerCase().contains("manger id : mngr13564"));
}

@Test
public void invalidLogin() {
  String username = "invalidUsername";
  String password = "invalidPassword";
  login.clickOnLoginButton(username, password);
  Assert.assertFalse(homePage.getHomePageDashboardUserName().toLowerCase().contains("manger id : mngr13564"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions and I finally I come up with some thing like this.

Comment: @Test()
   @Parameters({ "sUsername", "sPassword" })
   public void TestValidLogin(String sUsername,String sPassword) {
    login.loginToGuru99(sUsername, sPassword);    
    Assert.assertTrue(homePage.getHomePageDashboardUserName().toLowerCase().contains("manger id : mngr13564"));
   }

Comment: @Test()
   @Parameters({ "sUsername", "sPassword" })
   public void TestInValidLogin(String sUsername,String sPassword) {
    login.loginToGuru99(sUsername, sPassword);
    Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }

Comment: Thanks peetya for pointing it out. I was under the assumption that if the test reachs till alert.accept step then i can consider the test as Passed that is the reason I scripted in that way.

But based on your comments I made changes
   @Test()
   @Parameters({ "sUsername", "sPassword" })
   public void TestInValidLogin(String sUsername,String sPassword) {
    login.loginToGuru99(sUsername, sPassword);
    Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alerttxt=alert.getText();
    alert.accept();
    Assert.assertTrue(alerttxt.equalsIgnoreCase("User or Password is not valid"));
   }

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask these kind of questions .if anybody thinks its inappropriate then I can delete this question

As I said I just started learning selenium I want to know what all are the tools i need to lean in order to support my learning in selenium .So far I am using selenium web driver2 for scripting, TestNG for organizing Test and Maven for all dependency file and build. Please let me know if i need to know any more tools to start of with Selenium testing in more professional way.